# Line feeds in Arduino, type in via serial monitor, get method

Tags: c++, url, get, arduino

I am trying to type in description via the serial monitor of Arduino Uno, then pass the value via the get method. I tried but the result is that the code line feeds automatically and the get method failed, the value is in the next line. I don't know why.

```
String zzz;
char description[80];
zzz= Serial.readStringUntil('#');
zzz.toCharArray(description,80);
sprintf(aaa,"The description is:%s",description);
Serial.println(aaa);
```

A function to get the value:

```
void writesession(){
sprintf (str, "GET /test/newsession2.php?ardid=%d&description=%s",ardid,description);
sendurlandrecv();}
```

I also tried this:

```
Serial.println("Please enter the description in 15s");
Serial.readBytesUntil('#',description,80);
sprintf(aaa,"The description is:%s",description);
Serial.println(aaa);
```

But all results are like this:

[image: what shows in the serial monitor]

Comment: What I want to achieve is pass something typed via serial monitor to the server

Comment: Probably because you are sending a new line character.

Comment: thanks,it is because of the setting of the serial monitor